# I'm getting XMLStreamException at [row,col]:[1,2]

Tags: java, xml, hibernate

I suddenly have started getting XMLStreamException in my project. Yesterday it worked just fine, today I made some minor changes and it's broken. I tried to rebase to previous versions, but nothing changed at all.

Here is my xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">org.postgresql.Driver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5433/logistica</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">testUser</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password">pass</property>
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql">true</property>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL9Dialect</property>

        <mapping class="com.log.iei.logistica.data.entities.ClientEntity" />
        <mapping class="com.log.iei.logistica.data.entities.ContractEntity" />
        <mapping class="com.log.iei.logistica.data.entities.ContainerEntity" />
        <mapping class="com.log.iei.logistica.data.entities.VehicleEntity" />
        <mapping class="com.log.iei.logistica.data.entities.TransactionEntity" />

    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

And exception:

```
org.hibernate.HibernateException: Error accessing stax stream
    at org.hibernate.boot.cfgxml.internal.JaxbCfgProcessor.unmarshal(JaxbCfgProcessor.java:107)
    at org.hibernate.boot.cfgxml.internal.JaxbCfgProcessor.unmarshal(JaxbCfgProcessor.java:65)
    at org.hibernate.boot.cfgxml.internal.ConfigLoader.loadConfigXmlResource(ConfigLoader.java:57)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistryBuilder.configure(StandardServiceRegistryBuilder.java:165)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:258)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:244)
    at com.log.iei.logistica.managers.HibernateSessionManager.getSessionFactory(HibernateSessionManager.java:18)
    at com.log.iei.logistica.data.controllers.Services.GenericDao.getSession(GenericDao.java:78)
    at com.log.iei.logistica.data.controllers.Services.GenericDao.findAll(GenericDao.java:58)
    at com.log.iei.logistica.data.controllers.Services.VehicleService.findAll(VehicleService.java:50)
    at com.log.iei.logistica.gui.cargo.CargoPage.init(CargoPage.java:27)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
.........
.......
Caused by: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: ParseError at [row,col]:[1,2]
Message: The markup declarations contained or pointed to by the document type declaration must be well-formed.
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLStreamReaderImpl.next(XMLStreamReaderImpl.java:604)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.stream.XMLEventReaderImpl.peek(XMLEventReaderImpl.java:276)
    at org.hibernate.boot.cfgxml.internal.JaxbCfgProcessor.unmarshal(JaxbCfgProcessor.java:103)
    ... 36 more
```

Comment: Which Hibernate Version are you using?

Comment: I use 5.4.3.Final

Comment: Can you try to remove the Doctype?

Comment: Thanks, now it's working again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I began having the same issue. I hadn't updated anything, but restarting tomcat failed with lots of new exceptions. I noticed the below file was updated today and wondered if it was the source (it is referenced in each of my entity mappings):

http://hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd

So I updated my mappings to use the DTD from here:"hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd" - and that works. So it does appear to be caused by the Hibernate's updated DTD file.

I guess your options are:

1. figure out what hibernate wants in the updated dtd
2. use the dtd from another source like sourceforge
3. use the dtd from your hibernate jar like this: "classpath://org/hibernate/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd"

Comment: Thanks. I also noticed that, but I wasn't able to determine the difference by myself. In my case, I just needed to add www before URL address...